# Is it possible to compile together OS and web server/server apps into a single executable?

Tags: linux, security

I was discussing with a friend the idea of a "single application compiled server", in which the server is compiled together only with the its dependencies into a single executable. Nothing else is on the server. There is no shell and nothing else there.

The idea being that if there is nothing but an integrated executable that includes the bits of the OS and drivers needed plus the web server and application code, then this would be much more secure than a server that can be logged in to.

Does this make sense, is it possible, would it be more secure?

Comment: If there is no shell.. how would you manage it? All management done via a web management? There already have been some "Server" Linux distribution with LAMP pre-installed, and nothing else.. is that what you meant?

Comment: You're over thinking the "security" aspect of things and adding unnecessary complexity.  You could accomplish something similar to what you're talking about by using Java and building a java based app, compiled and able to run in an Java Run Time Environment, but that's the best you're going to get if you want it to be able to run on multiple platforms; or you could build a web app following best practices for security and adding SSL and 2-factor authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't roll everything into a single executable, but with Linux you can:

- compile a kernel that has only what you need, including only drivers you want.  You can compile only required drivers directly in the kernel and disable module loading.  If your hardware changes you'll need to recompile.  This is hard, very hard if you don't already have a working system with the right build tools and a compiler.
- create your own `init` that would only spawn your webserver and keep it running if it dies.  This is hard.
- only include the executables and dependent libraries you need for that webserver and anything it depends on.  This is hard.
- be prepared to create a program that installs this, and update all of this yourself as security fixes come available.  This is very hard.

Achieving the above is difficult but not impossible.  With a minimal Debian install and only installing the software you need, you can come pretty close and get the benefit of regular updates and an easy package management system if you change your mind about things.  You can also still compile your own kernel in the manner above and Debian will provide tools to do that.

Comment: So do you think this would be any more secure?

Comment: It's consistent with the principle of keeping as small of an "attack surface" as possible.